# Turning clusters assigned through numpy array into separate datasets

Tags: python, database, numpy, cluster-analysis

I have a very large dataset that I am running a clustering model on.  The clustering outputs a numpy array formatted as such:

```
    [ 0 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 2 0 1 2 1 0 2 2 0 0 1 ... ]
```

I want to take the original dataset, and create three datasets based on the array.  How would I go about this?

Initial Dataset Work:

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
 raw_data = pd.read_csv("LendingClub2012to2013.csv", low_memory = False, skiprows=[0])

 //Some cleaning done, target leakage removed, dummies created, imputation, etc.

 clean_data = raw_data.drop(text2d + leakage2d + noinfo2d + irr2d, axis = 1)
```

Comment: .Show us code!!

Comment: How many data points and how many clusters?

Comment: Currently I am working with three clusters, 171483 x 115 in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your dataset is a numpy array. Try creating masks to select the elements you want from the original data set. Some verbose code:

```
# Your original data set (2d numpy array)
orig_data = ...
# The cluster assignments output by the algorithm (1d numpy array)
cluster_assignments = ...

clusters = []
for cluster_id in xrange(3):
    mask = (cluster_assignments == cluster_id)
    clusters.append(orig_data[mask])
```

A more concise version:

```
clusters = [orig_data[cluster_assignments == id] for id in xrange(3))]
```

If your dataset is a pandas Dataframe rather than a numpy array, simple replace `orig_data[...]` with `orig_data.loc[...]`.

The output of this code is a list `clusters` in which each element is a dataset with the data for just one of the clusters.

Comment: @Jgreen727 - glad to help; please accept this answer if it satisfies your question!